# I am trying to get JSON response in spring mvc to display in front end?

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I am trying to just get a json response in my webpage but it is not working .
I have a Shop  Pojo class
My controller code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfc/brands")
public class JSONController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[] { "mkyong1", "mkyong2" });
        return shop;

    }
}
```

I am getting a Json Response in the url http://localhost:9080/FirstSpringMVCProject/kfc/brands/rahul

but the problem is i want to display this json object 
which comes like {"name":"rahul","staffName":["john","rohan"]}
to display in the front end using jquery.
how do i do that

I am not using Maven this is a demo as i am learning how to get JSON in spring mvc can you please help

Comment: In @RequestMapping(value = **"{name}"**, method = RequestMethod.GET), you don't need value="{name}"

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/name", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {
do anything here
}
```

than get your json in javascript

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:9080/FirstSpringMVCProject/kfc/brands/name", function (jsonData) {

}
```

Now you have jsonData object in which you have all json data, now display it in front end according to your need.

Comment: ahmad i added 
$('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + jsonData.name + '</p>');
in a index.html but where to place this file  in webinf or outside as when placing outside or inside it telling resource not available

stack trace is

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCProject/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Comment: you should place your index.html file in WebContent folder.